# unable to open the default mail client

Tags: c#

I am using following code to open the default mail client

```
using (Process mailProcess = new Process())
{
     ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
     processInfo.FileName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            "mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body={2}", 
                             sendToAddress.Address, subject, message);
     processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
     processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
     mailProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
     Process.Start(processInfo);
}
```

It starts the process but doesn't show mail client. Actually when I am using only localhost it doesn't open the mail client although it starts the process.

When I am using localhost: it works.

Can anybosy hel me?

Comment: It should pick default mail client by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will start default email client

```
 var process = @"mailto:some.guy@someplace.com?subject=an email&body=see attachment";
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(process);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var url = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            "mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body={2}", 
                             sendToAddress.Address, subject, message);
Process.Start(url);
```

You have to use `System.Diagnostics;`